# What is the best way to format a large has_many through line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question is about code style.

I have this line in one of my models:

```
has_many :owning_artists, :through => :artist_tracks, :source => :artist, :conditions => { :artist_tracks => { :artistic_role_id => 1, :another_memeber => 42 } }
```

What is the best way to break this up on multiple lines, and indented of course, and what would it would look like?

I'd love to hear a more general recommendation/guideline for how to break up and indent nested hashes too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
has_many :owning_artists, {
  :through => :artist_tracks,
  :source => :artist,
  :conditions => {
    :artist_tracks => {
      :artistic_role_id => 1,
      :another_memeber => 42
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't really add to this other than to say that if the `artist_tracks` hash had more than one member I would break those on to individual lines as well, indented accordingly.